# Why do buffers decrease delay?

Tags: circuit-analysis, h-bridge, delay, propagation

Lots of people break up wires into stages to decrease RC delay. This makes sense to reduce the wire L and thus capacitance, but doesn’t the time for the signals to propagate through the buffers add delay as well?

Comment: The answer to your question is:  yes, buffers add delay.  

There are multiple reasons to use buffers.  One of them can be to compensate for the transmission line.  Difficult to give a general answer since the type of signal nor wire lengths are unknown here.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose the wire is connecting gate A to gate B, and it is very long. Without buffers A has to drive both the wire capacitance and gate B's capacitance or C_load. By inserting buffers we are both reducing the wire length and increasing the driving capability to charge gate B's capacitance. In other words, they were added to help gate A provide the current necessary to charge the load capacitance.

We cannot, however, insert infinite number of them because adding too much will make the delay worse as they themselves have input capacitances.  There is a tradeoff between the number of buffers and the desired delay for the interconnect. You can look up logical effort delay for more info.